# Does Essence Scatter affect Artifact Creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does the Instant [Essence Scatter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Essence%20Scatter) affect Artifact Creature spells such as [Stuffy Doll](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stuffy%20Doll)?

Comment: "205.1. The type line is printed directly below the illustration. It contains the card’s card type(s). It also contains the card’s subtype(s) and supertype(s), if applicable." Stuffy Doll has two types: artifact and creature. As such, it is a creature.

Comment: Note that it only affects Stuffy Doll *spells*, not Stuffy Doll permanents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes

From a ruling on the Essence Scatter Gatherer entry:

> A "creature spell" is any spell with the type Creature, **even if it has other types such as Artifact or Enchantment**. Older cards of type Summon are also Creature spells.

Comment: Was this the case in the past for Remove Soul and Summon spells? As then Artifact Creatures were not Summon spells, while Summon Elf would be a summon spell.

Comment: @Nick The Oracle text on [Remove Soul](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=129699) reads *"Counter target **creature** spell."* The Oracle text has precedence over the words written on the card, even in casual play. Other than card name, Remove Soul is identical to [Essence Scatter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=276209).